# Notating using ties on a 4/4 music

Tags: notation, rhythm, time-signatures

I am required to notate a note that is played on the 'and' of 1 and ring for the remaining beats of a 4/4 measure.

My choices is:

1. I use a quaver rest followed by a quaver tied to a dotted minim in which case I will not be distinguishing the half way mark at 3.
2. Or should I have a quaver rest followed by a dotted crotchet tied to a minim where I will be emphasizing on the midpoint of the bar.

Which one of the two options is correct and why?

Comment: If not marking the middle of the bar is an option, why use ties at all? You could simply write a double-dotted note.

Comment: The main point of seeing a 4/4 bar to be split into halves is to be able to read what's in the second half more easily. Here there's little point, as the note carries through to the end.

Answer (score 6):

There are actually four possibilities:
[image]

IMHO all of these are acceptable, although I find the first one easiest to read. The third one looks unneccessarily complicated and the fourth looks a bit 'unusual', but would probably be a good choice if there was half a page of this rhythm.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it differently. Eighth rest, eighth note tied to quarter note tied to half note. (I can't post graphics easily.) The suggested pattern avoids breaking any "normal" divisions and makes sight reading easier.